# JupyterLab with Naive Bayes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, naivebayes, train-test-split

I am trying to detect quillbot paraphrasing by using naive bayes in jupyter notebook. My dataset has 2 columns, first column is filled with a sample text from various sources around 250 words. the second column is type, and that is set to either 1 if it is parahrased or 0 if it is the original text. Ive got this code so far but I am getting some errors. here is a link to my dataset: `https://pastebin.com/ts8SLGHq` and here is my code:

```
from pydataset import data
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('Desktop/Dataset.csv', encoding='utf-8')

# specify the column names
df.columns = ['text', 'type']

# split the dataset into train and test sets
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# convert text data into numerical features
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_df['text'])
X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_df['text'])
y_train = train_df['type'].values
y_test = test_df['type'].values

# initialize a Gaussian Naive Bayes model
model = GaussianNB()

# train the model on the train set
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# evaluate the model on the test set
accuracy = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Model accuracy on test set: {:.2f}%".format(accuracy * 100))
```

and here is the error I am getting:

````
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[184], line 5
      2 model = GaussianNB()
      4 # train the model on the train set
----> 5 model.fit(X_train, y_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py:267, in GaussianNB.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    265 self._validate_params()
    266 y = self._validate_data(y=y)
--> 267 return self._partial_fit(
    268     X, y, np.unique(y), _refit=True, sample_weight=sample_weight
    269 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py:428, in GaussianNB._partial_fit(self, X, y, classes, _refit, sample_weight)
    425     self.classes_ = None
    427 first_call = _check_partial_fit_first_call(self, classes)
--> 428 X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, reset=first_call)
    429 if sample_weight is not None:
    430     sample_weight = _check_sample_weight(sample_weight, X)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:565, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    563         y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    564     else:
--> 565         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    566     out = X, y
    568 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:1106, in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1101         estimator_name = _check_estimator_name(estimator)
   1102     raise ValueError(
   1103         f"{estimator_name} requires y to be passed, but the target y is None"
   1104     )
-> 1106 X = check_array(
   1107     X,
   1108     accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   1109     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
   1110     dtype=dtype,
   1111     order=order,
   1112     copy=copy,
   1113     force_all_finite=force_all_finite,
   1114     ensure_2d=ensure_2d,
   1115     allow_nd=allow_nd,
   1116     ensure_min_samples=ensure_min_samples,
   1117     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
   1118     estimator=estimator,
   1119     input_name="X",
   1120 )
   1122 y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric, estimator=estimator)
   1124 check_consistent_length(X, y)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:845, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    843 if sp.issparse(array):
    844     _ensure_no_complex_data(array)
--> 845     array = _ensure_sparse_format(
    846         array,
    847         accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
    848         dtype=dtype,
    849         copy=copy,
    850         force_all_finite=force_all_finite,
    851         accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
    852         estimator_name=estimator_name,
    853         input_name=input_name,
    854     )
    855 else:
    856     # If np.array(..) gives ComplexWarning, then we convert the warning
    857     # to an error. This is needed because specifying a non complex
    858     # dtype to the function converts complex to real dtype,
    859     # thereby passing the test made in the lines following the scope
    860     # of warnings context manager.
    861     with warnings.catch_warnings():
````

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:522, in _ensure_sparse_format(spmatrix, accept_sparse, dtype, copy, force_all_finite, accept_large_sparse, estimator_name, input_name)
519 _check_large_sparse(spmatrix, accept_large_sparse)
521 if accept_sparse is False:
--> 522     raise TypeError(
523         "A sparse matrix was passed, but dense "
524         "data is required. Use X.toarray() to "
525         "convert to a dense numpy array."
526     )
527 elif isinstance(accept_sparse, (list, tuple)):
528     if len(accept_sparse) == 0:

TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.`

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

I first tried to convert the data into numerical features but either I did it wrong or there is another issue

Comment: I suspect you mean Python in the places you use 'JupyterLab' (post title). 'Jupyter Notebook' (post), or 'Jupyter-Notebook' (tag list). Tagging things correctly will help your issue get seen. JupyterLab & Jupyter Notbeook will run different languages using kernels, & so they are language agnostic. One way to evaluate is if you issue should focus on JupyterLab / Notebook, is to ask yourself if you ran the same code as a Python script on the command line, if you'd have the same issue? If so, then you're not dealing with a Jupyter issue, although **it is always good to say where running code**.

Answer (score 0):

Convert sparse matrix to NumPy array

```
X_train.todense()
```